# Why Xcode's template has no content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

When I use Xcode, I made a new file.

It's UITableViewController template.

But It doesn't have any contents.

Why?

[image: Choosing file]

[image]

[image: No contents]

Comment: when you create new files no content is there manually you have to write the content

Comment: This is what they call "programming".

Comment: What do you expect? All it says is that you get a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user does not understand that the content must be written.

Comment: The OP may be expecting some boilerplate code for the data source and delegate methods.

Comment: @Hot Licks, Raviraj Jadeja and LuckyLuke: This was a good question for which a real answer existed. Yet the question got a down-vote and three close votes. Please, we really need to be a little easier on those who ask questions, less gun-slinger kill the question, harm the OP's rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best guess is that you choose the "Objective-C class" icon under the "OS X" section, not under the "iOS" section. Since "OS X" does not have a class `UITableViewController` there was no boilerplate code generated. Try again under the "iOS" section.

Comment: Saved a lot of head scratching – thanks!